# How do I access an attribute from the outer node inside an inner condition?

Tags: xpath

I want to perform the following XPath:
/Configs/Category/InputMenu/Config[@Value = 'DualPack' and (/Configs/Category/MasterSlave/Config[@No = ./@No]/@Value = 'Master')]

Where the "./@No" in the part"[@No = ./@No]" is from /Configs/Category/InputMenu/Config@No, not from /Configs/Category/MasterSlave/Config@No

How can I specify that the ./@No is from that outer node?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 2, you could use for to simulate the let of XQuery:

```
/Configs/Category/InputMenu/Config[@Value = 'DualPack' and (for $no in ./@No return /Configs/Category/MasterSlave/Config[@No = $no]/@Value = 'Master')]
```

Otherwise you could turn it around, and check if the No attribute is equal to the No attribute of one element that has a Master value (instead checking if the value of one element with the same No attribute is Master).

```
/Configs/Category/InputMenu/Config[@Value = 'DualPack' and @No = /Configs/Category/MasterSlave/Config[@Value = 'Master']/@No]
```